# How can I get access to object properties (arraycollection)?

Tags: php, arrays, json, symfony, object

This is my object `products`:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => Products {#8662 ▼
    -id: 5
    -name: "lion"
    -unique_id: "7726d59574"
    -productgroup: PersistentCollection {#8763 ▼
      -snapshot: array:2 [ …2]
      -owner: Products {#8662}
      -association: array:20 [ …20]
      -em: EntityManager {#4326 …11}
      -backRefFieldName: null
      -typeClass: ClassMetadata {#8294 …}
      -isDirty: false
      #collection: ArrayCollection {#8666 ▼
        -elements: array:2 [▼
          0 => Productgroup {#8765 ▼
            -id: 5
            -name: "Mammals"
            -unique_id: "12102400f9"
          }
          1 => Productgroup {#8769 ▼
            -id: 7
            -name: "Fish"
            -unique_id: "f0fbfa5c19"
          }
        ]
      }
      #initialized: true
    }
  }
]
```

When I create json file like this...

```
$result = $serializer->serialize($products, 'json');
```

...I get this result:

```
[{"id":5,"uniqueId":"7726d59574","name":"lion","productgroup":[{"id":5,"uniqueId":"12102400f9","name":"Mammals"},{"id":7,"uniqueId":"f0fbfa5c19","name":"Fish"}]}]
```

But the result that I need is only productgroup. So this is what I try to achieve:

```
[{"id":5,"uniqueId":"12102400f9","name":"Mammals"},{"id":7,"uniqueId":"f0fbfa5c19","name":"Fish"}]
```

This was my first approach:

```
$data = $products->productgroup;
$result = $serializer->serialize($data, 'json');
```

But I got the error message:

> Notice: Trying to get property 'productgroup' of non-object

I thought, oh ok, this means, `products` is not an object, so I tried this:

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $data = $product['productgroup'];
}
$result = $serializer->serialize($data, 'json');
```

But now I get the error:

> Cannot use object of type App\Entity\Products as array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use something like this:

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $data = $product->getProductGroup();
}
```

Method `getProductGroup` must exists into your entity, if not you can have something similar I think.

Comment: Glad to help you, remember to accept the answer to help other developers with your same problem @marila